# Need help organizing multiple containers, buttons, and modals

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, modal-dialog

I'm trying to make a grid of photos that when hovered over display a button that can be used to open a modal. After successfully getting one photo to function this way, I tried to start introducing more photos, but now I can't open the modal from the first button any more.

Here's the code I'm using so far for reference:

```css
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h3>Modal Title 1</h3>
    <p>Modal Text 1
</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/ABFh1yeARivImN6pNH7kuatn60gVuTBKQO9dbkUPSa2nQQWvlgOMt4GIkI5ZlWvHDV1jhXJQ1JqmPPSRwqdwDZ360SPlxnHG7as4GypQWPvCGa0_IiZ8MY-dxF3qQ3azldvGF3P3pFUVOe5oi0pL4cTQiLbj4wqyX7f-SSYaVwD88sU8B-avSdROijI0_3zOecUEfMl9Hrx3uWviDREGperqRhJ7-YaB1VM-LRPh5ESKN92YeEdpM41tIIUL-CAbzcffQYNncc-XUi8TMpOdLL2lvH_s6W1kH70H4PuEt8b0fn5I6oAg8ami7_6GJSK4nPUYxWbrbqiAgrmv2U-7aYeWhtkiRf0l8JDGoP9BVblqcg/p.jpeg?fv_content=true&size_mode=5" alt="Fiona Garufi" style="width:100%">
  <button1 id="myBtn1" class="btn">Button Text 1</button>
  </div>

<!-- The Modal 2-->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content 2-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h3>Modal Title 2</h3>
    <p>Modal Text 2
</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/ABFh1yeARivImN6pNH7kuatn60gVuTBKQO9dbkUPSa2nQQWvlgOMt4GIkI5ZlWvHDV1jhXJQ1JqmPPSRwqdwDZ360SPlxnHG7as4GypQWPvCGa0_IiZ8MY-dxF3qQ3azldvGF3P3pFUVOe5oi0pL4cTQiLbj4wqyX7f-SSYaVwD88sU8B-avSdROijI0_3zOecUEfMl9Hrx3uWviDREGperqRhJ7-YaB1VM-LRPh5ESKN92YeEdpM41tIIUL-CAbzcffQYNncc-XUi8TMpOdLL2lvH_s6W1kH70H4PuEt8b0fn5I6oAg8ami7_6GJSK4nPUYxWbrbqiAgrmv2U-7aYeWhtkiRf0l8JDGoP9BVblqcg/p.jpeg?fv_content=true&size_mode=5" alt="Fiona Garufi" style="width:100%">
  <button1 id="myBtn2" class="btn">Button Text 2</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>  
// Get the first modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal1");

// Get the first button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the second modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal2");

// Get the second button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #673589;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  transition: .4s ease;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transition: .4s ease;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(235,235,235,.5);
  opacity: 0;
  color: #351B47;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  padding: 16px 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  id: "myBtn";
}

.container:hover .btn{

  opacity: 1;
}
.container:hover {
    opacity: .75;
}

  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your using the id in your javascript your only binding the modal only once in the DOM, change it to use the class name instead, I would also recommend improving your CSS

```js
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button.btn");

// All page modals
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
 }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
    }
 }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
     for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
     }
    }
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #673589;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  transition: .4s ease;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transition: .4s ease;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(235,235,235,.5);
  opacity: 0;
  color: #351B47;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  padding: 16px 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  id: "myBtn";
}

.container:hover .btn{

  opacity: 1;
}
.container:hover {
    opacity: .75;
}

  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h3>Modal Title 1</h3>
    <p>Modal Text 1
</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Fiona Garufi" style="width:100%">
  <button href="#myModal1" id="myBtn1" class="btn">Button Text 1</button>
  </div>

<!-- The Modal 2-->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content 2-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h3>Modal Title 2</h3>
    <p>Modal Text 2
</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Fiona Garufi" style="width:100%">
  <button href="#myModal2" id="myBtn2" class="btn">Button Text 2</button>

</div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check how I changed the javascript and ran the snippet it opens both modals now when clicking on them

Comment: Give me a sec and ill update the javascript so it could be more universal to use

Comment: Ok try now this javascript now will close by the X or clicking out of the modal it will also allow you to add as many modal windows and buttons you wish all you would need to do is add each modal with a unique id and add that id to the href in the button I would also change the button to a tags but for now I left it similiar to what you had already on your markup

Comment: Yup, now this is a nice answer, it doesn't only give a fish to OP, it teaches them to fish.

Comment: Thank you much! That works perfectly. I'm really new to writing code (if you couldn't tell by my shoddy code), and your explanation cleared up an issue that's confounded me for days.